# Jira API Automation - REST Assured

Tags: java, json, rest, jira-rest-api

Am trying to automate Jira Issue Creation via REST API with Java Rest Assured. The following are my code snippets.

I need to reframe the following JSON in Java and pass it to the Body.

```
{
"fields": {
    "project": {
        "id": "13204"
    },
    "summary": "welcome to testing1",
    "issuetype": {
        "id": "3"
    },
    "reporter": {
        "name": "parthiban.selvaraj"
    },
    "priority": {
        "id": "3"
    },
    "description": "description",
     "customfield_10201": {
       "id": "10608"
    }
}
```

}

Below is my Java code with getter and setter:

```java
package jira;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.authentication.PreemptiveBasicAuthScheme;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import io.restassured.http.Method;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;
import java.util.List;
public class home {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        System.out.println("Welcome");
        RestAssured.baseURI = "http://##.###.##.##:####/jira/rest/api/2/issue/";
        PreemptiveBasicAuthScheme authScheme = new PreemptiveBasicAuthScheme();
        authScheme.setUserName("########");
        authScheme.setPassword("#######");
        RestAssured.authentication = authScheme;
        getterSetter values=new getterSetter();
        values.setProject(13204);
        values.setSummary("Checking via REST Assured");
        values.setIssueType(3);
        values.setReporter("#######");
        values.setPriority(3);
        values.setDescription("Welcome to JAVA World");
        //Updating sprint name custom field value
        values.setCustomfield_10201(10608);
        Gson gson=new Gson();
        String json= gson.toJson(values);
        System.out.println("JSON Values " + json);
        RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given().header("Content-Type", 
        "application/json").body(json);
        System.out.println(httpRequest + " Request ");
        Response response = httpRequest.request(Method.POST, "");
        System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
        String responseBody = response.getBody().asString();
        System.out.println("response " + responseBody);
        JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(responseBody);
    }
}
```

Getter and Setter File:

```java
    package jira;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
    //@XmlRootElement
    public class getterSetter {
        private int project;
        private int issueType;
        private String reporter;
        private String summary;
        private int priority;
        private String description;
        private int customfield_10201;
        public String getSummary() {
            return summary;
        }

        public void setSummary(String summary) {
            this.summary = summary;
        }

        public void setProject(int project){
            this.project=project;
        }

        public int getProject() {
            return project;
        }

        public int getIssueType() {
            return issueType;
        }

        public void setIssueType(int issueType) {
            this.issueType = issueType;
        }

        public String getReporter() {
            return reporter;
        }

        public void setReporter(String reporter) {
            this.reporter = reporter;
        }

        public int getPriority() {
            return priority;
        }
        public void setPriority(int  priority) {
            this.priority = priority;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public int getCustomfield_10201() {
            return customfield_10201;
        }

        public void setCustomfield_10201(int customfield_10201) {
            this.customfield_10201 = customfield_10201;
        }
      }
```

I understand JSON format which I am passing through request Body is wrong. Can anyone help me to pass correct JSON format in Request Body.
I tested in Postman with the above JSON format Issue created successfully in my Instance.

For the above code am hitting with 
response code 500 and Internal Server Error.

Comment: Your `getterSetter` class doesn't meet the JSON format for creating issue to Jira. You can see the difference by `System.out.println("JSON Values " + json);` which is already in your code.

Comment: Yes, my getter & setter class doesn't meet the JSON format. Can you tell me how to write it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the JSON string as the payload to create Jira issue, you can directly create several corresponding classes as follows:

```
class IssueInfo {
    private Field fields;
    //general getters and setters
}

class Field {
    private Project project;
    private String summary;
    private IssueType issuetype;
    private Reporter reporter;
    private Priority priority;
    private String description;
    private Customfield10201 customfield_10201;
    //general getters and setters
}

class Project {
    private String id;
    //general getters and setters
}

class IssueType {
    private String id;
    //general getters and setters
}

class Reporter {
    private String name;
    //general getters and setters
}

class Priority {
    private String id;
    //general getters and setters
}

class Customfield10201 {
    private String id;
    //general getters and setters
}
```

After assigning value of each required field, you can pass the instance of `IssueInfo` as request body.